# How to track the device location using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an application in which there is 1 Master user and several other Child user(Consider 5 Child users).

How can Master user track the real time location of all the other 5 Child users using Phonegap (I am developing App using Android platform).

I want to do it using geolocation from a Phonegap application

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this "peer-to-peer" - i.e the child device passing its location directly to a master device. Your best bet is probably to mediate it via a server: i.e. each child sends its location to a remote server; master polls the server for location updates of children.